# Windows live usb boot falied

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I am unable to boot into my windows live usb after Installing Ubuntu (single boot) on my PC. Whenever I try to boot into windows live usb it says **Reboot and select a proper boot device or Insert boot media In selected boot device and press a key**
I tried resetting my BIOS, removing gurb and repairing mbr but nothing happened.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dK37.jpg)

Comment: It says nothing active.  Use gparted or something else to make your USB partition "active" first.

Comment: do you have any knowledge on how to active a partition